# How do I terminate a loop in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot, and I created a command where whenever someone executes the command "!ping @ example", then it would ping @example once every minute until @example stops it. I have created the loop successfully, however, I can't terminate the loop.

```
var interval = setInterval (function () {
  const user = message.mentions.users.first();
            message.channel.send('You have been pinged!' + '\n' + '<@' + user + '>')

        }, 1 * 60000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearInterval()` method which clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method.

```
clearInterval(interval);
```